# Access to constraint inside a class

Tags: swift, constraints

Maybe this topic has already been talked about, but I couldn't find anything...

Here is the idea: I would like to create a class that when set to a Constraint, would actually have an impact on the constraint's value depending on the size of the screen.

The problem is, I don't know how exactly I could access this constraint once it's class is set to the one I want to create, but without setting an outlet of this constraint.

I do this request because I have serious issues with Auto-layout and can't really understand how to re-do a whole project with it. 
I used to work in a company that had such a class but I can't remember how it's exactly done...

Comment: "I have serious issues with Auto-layout and can't really understand how to re-do a whole project with it" In my opinion it would be better to understand it and redo the project with it. Autolayout is really extremely straightforward; it is neither magic nor mysterious.

Comment: try [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLYKjb-Uo9czzt2nz6f0FKnLpYF0sesVW) tutorial